# Prometheus inhibit alert selectively

Tags: prometheus, monitoring, sre, prometheus-alertmanager

I need to create an alerting system that has to notify when a particular condition (e.g. Tomcat goes down) is met.
Multiple remote servers deployed in different locations (with different time zones) host Tomcat services and are being monitored by Prometheus.
I need to receive the alert only from 8:05 to 22:45 local time so I proceed as follow:

1. Defined a custom rule "check_system_time_in_interval" that returns 1 if the server local time is in [8:05,22:45], 0 otherwise
2. Used rule 1) to define an alert *Inhibit alert during NO working hours* in "prometheus.rule.yml":

```
- name: quite_hours
  rules:
    - alert: Inhibit alert during NO working hours
      expr: check_system_time_in_interval==0
      labels:
        notification: none
        severity: critical
```

3. Defined a new inhibit_rule in "alertmanager.yml" file that inhibits the alert *TOMCAT down* (fires alert when TOMCAT service is out of service) when the monitored server time is not in the interval

```
inhibit_rules:
- source_match:
    alertname: Inhibit alert during NO working hours
  target_match_re:
    alertname: (TOMCAT down)
```

TOMCAT down uses a custom rule "tomcat_up" that checks if Tomcat is up or not.
Now it seems to work quite properly but with this approach I would have problems due to time zones: I need to be notified if the LOCAL time of the monitored server is in [8:05,22:45] even if Prometheus server is located to different time zone.

One simple solution would be to inhibit the alert only if the 'instance' label of check_system_time_in_interval time series is equals to 'instance' label of TOMCAT down (e.g. if check_system_time_in_interval{instance="10.41.0.118"}=0 and tomcat_up{instance="10.41.0.118}=1" then fire an alert) but I don't know how to modify "inhibit_rule" in order to do that.

Answer (score 0):

After a while, I came up with a trivial solution: adding a new label "timezone" and inhibit an alert only if "timezone" labels match.

Comment: I think you can also avoid the additional tz metric by using Prometheus time functions. Similar to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69717672/time-based-alerts-in-prometheus-alertmanager/69719774#69719774